# PHP print and echo not working

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I was making this form and I wanted to print some data but it is not displaying. What is wrong with it? Here's the code:

```
<form name="input" action="check.php" method="get">
            Unit number: 
            <input type="number" name="unit" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>

            <table>
            <tr><td class="check-table">
            <?php
            if($_GET[unit] = null) $output="<p>Please Enter A Unit Number</p>";
            echo $output;
            ?>
            </td></tr></table>
```

Please Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better way would be:

```
if (empty($_GET['unit'])) {
    $output="<p>Please Enter A Unit Number</p>";
    echo $output;
}
```

The reasons:

1. You check if variable exists
2. You use `'` quotes for array key name
3. You output `$output` variable only if it is necessary. And in your case - you output it even if it doesn't exist
4. You've also confused `==` (comparison operator) and `=` (assignment operator)

Comment: Thank you heaps! I know this was a dumb question but I really didnt know where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed the single quotes in the $_GET['unit']

```
<?php
            if($_GET['unit'] = null) $output="<p>Please Enter A Unit Number</p>";
            echo $output;
            ?>
```